# How do I cash out an Ameriprise Roth IRA and VUL?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira

I have two accounts with Ameriprise: a Roth IRA and a VUL.

I sent them a letter requesting the forms necessary to cash out all of my accounts, and listed the account numbers.

They only sent me a form 33300 "Life Insurance Loan or Surrender Request" ([forms page](http://www.ameriprise.com/customer-service/account-service-forms.asp)), which covers the VUL.

Which form do I need to use to cash out the Roth IRA (Ameriprise Brokerage)?  Or am I going about that the wrong way?  Do I need to transfer it to some sort of other account and then close that account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently there is no form, you just have to call them.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to handle an IRA is usually to decide what institution should take over the IRA custodian duties, and fill out that company's form for a direct transfer of the IRA assets from the current custodian (Ameriprise).  Things go much more smoothly this way, as the receiving company is motivated. (This may be related to why it is hard to find the right way to extract yourself from Ameriprise.)  They handle it, and you get the right tax statement at the end of the year.  If you receive the funds directly for an IRA, you have to make sure you handle the details in time or it will count as a withdrawal and your IRA becomes kaput and you're subject to applicable penalties.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I actually *want* to withdraw the funds completely, not roll it over.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the [Cash Distribution (200194)](http://www.ameriprise.com/global/docs/200194.pdf) form on the page you linked?

Comment: Looks like that might be it!  I'll check it out, thanks!